# Blender Python: scale a specific UI item?

Tags: python, user-interface, blender

I'm writing a simple and - for our needs very specific - Blender addon. As it has two main modes to select from, I would like to enlarge this "mode selector"-switch.

This image shows what I have and what I want (with placeholder icons for the two modes):

[image: Blender UI - orignal and scaled]

My code is something like this:

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_operation_mode = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = (
    ('1','Animation Curves','use animation curves', 'RNDCURVE', 1),
    ('2','Live Input','use live input', 'POSE_HLT', 2)
))

def draw(self, context):
    col = self.layout.column()
    # ...
    op_mode_row=col.row()
    op_mode_row.prop(context.scene, 'my_operation_mode', expand=True,text='',)
```

(I think from UI-Design perspective, having this option could become quite a mess within Blender. Still, it would be great if there is a way for specific reasons!)

Thanks and best regards!